# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, error only from android N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

this code, file explore. It works perfectly on Android 5, 6. but android N receive three receive error.
How can I solve? Thank you.

code:

```
    public class MainActivity  extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root;
    private TextView myPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        getDir(root);
    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if(!dirPath.equals(root))
        {
            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());
        }

        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            File file = files[i];

            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                }else{
                    if(isVideo(file)){
                        item.add(file.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);
    }
    public boolean isVideo(File file){
        String filename = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        String extension =  filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."), filename.length());

        switch (extension) {
            case ".3gp":
            case ".mpg":
            case ".mpeg":
            case ".mpe":
            case ".mp4":
            case ".avi":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead()){
                getDir(path.get(position));
            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_folder_open_black_24dp)
                        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            }
        }else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_folder_open_black_24dp)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

        }
    }

}
```

logcat:

```
04-09 17:52:20.830 11702-11702/ro.vrt.exploerfile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: ro.vrt.exploerfile, PID: 11702
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ro.vrt.exploerfile/ro.vrt.exploerfile.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=-1
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5849)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:763)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=-1
                                                                    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1903)
                                                                    at ro.vrt.exploerfile.MainActivity.isVideo(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                                    at ro.vrt.exploerfile.MainActivity.getDir(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                    at ro.vrt.exploerfile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6570)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5849) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:763) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
```

and the problem code:

```
 String extension =  filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."), filename.length());

if(isVideo(file)){

  getDir(root);
```

that big changes will be between earlier versions and N, or is currently not stable?

edit:

i am intent this:

```
        String extension = "";
    String filename = file.getName().toLowerCase();
    int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i >= 0) {
        extension = filename.substring(i -1);
    }


   /*  String ext = null;
    String s = file.getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
        ext = s.substring(i).toLowerCase();
    }*/

    switch (extension) {
        case ".3gp":
        case ".mpg":
        case ".mpeg":
        case ".mpe":
        case ".mp4":
        case ".avi":
        case ".m3u8":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
```

is work from androi N , but not show the files .mp4 .m3u8 .avi etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the problem is that you are not validating your inputs. You are assuming that every `File` passed to `isVideo()` has a `.` in its path somewhere. That is not a requirement, particularly for a directory that is not under your control, such as [the root of external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Check the result of `filename.lastIndexOf(".")` — if it is -1, then there is no file extension.

Also, [if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permissions-dont-work-even-if-i-have-declared-them), you need to handle `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` using the runtime permission system, which your code does not appear to have.

Comment: n android it go, but not shows   .mp4  .avi etc ,          String extension = "";
        String filename = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i >= 0) {
            extension = filename.substring(i -1);
        }
        switch (extension) {
            case ".3gp":
            case ".mpg":
            case ".mpeg":
            case ".mpe":
            case ".mp4":
            case ".avi":
            case ".m3u8":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }